# Changing the Color of Coreplot Tick Marks

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a CorePlot graph that i'm trying to change to be a different color. I have changed all the labels, and the axes, the grid lines, the title, to be this uniform color.  Only thing I'm having trouble is changing the color of the tick marks that correspond to values on the y and x axis.  I'm sure it's one line of code to do this but I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything that corresponded to this. I figured changing the color the grid lines would change the color the tick marks since they are a extension of the grid lines outsides the axes. I can attach a picture if this is hard to visualize what I'm referring to. Thanks for any help on this simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `majorTickLineStyle` for the major tick marks and the `minorTickLineStyle` for the minor ticks.

Answer (score 0):

First set up a MutableLineStyle:

```
// Configure Line-Style //
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
```

Get a reference to the axisSet //

```
// Get the Graph's axis set //
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostViewRRDataValues.hostedGraph.axisSet;
```

Then apply the LineStyle to for the minor and major Tick //

```
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = tickLineStyle; 
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = tickLineStyle;
```

Or set to nil if you do not want any thick marks at all

```
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = nil; // No minorTickLines
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = nil; // No majorTickLines
```